# Translation of "How far back?" in the context of time

Tags: traducción, tiempo

How would I say "How far back do they want me to go?"  The context of the question is that I was filling out an application where they wanted my work history.  I was attempting to ask the person helping me "How far back do they want me to go in my work history?".  The best I could come up with was "Que tan lejos para atras quieren que voy con mi historia de trabajo".  He understood what I meant but I am certain this was nothing close to correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say something like this (I'm using third person singular because I suppose it is in a very formal environment so I would use "Usted" as subject):

If you want to detail it from the past to the present:

> ¿Desde cuándo quiere que detalle mi actividad laboral?

If you want to detail it from the present to the past:

> ¿Hasta cuándo quiere que detalle mi actividad laboral?

Answer (score 3):

In Spain, the most usual translation is *hasta cuándo quieres que llegue*; for example:

> How far back do you want me to go filling out the form?
>
> ¿Hasta cuándo quieres que llegue rellenando el formulario?